# Spring: How to Redirect URL Without Resetting Form Input

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, redirect

I'm trying to create a form with validation & I want to make if there's an error when submitting, the page will redirect back to the form but the inputted values should stay. I use redirect url & I knew that redirect will reset all inputted values so if there's error when submitting, the page will redirect back to the form but the inputted values are gone. How do I solve this? Is there any way to redirect url without redirect?

Here's my Controller (CREATE_FORM is my form & POST_FORM is my submit):

```
private static final String CREATE_FORM = "/config/{channelCode}/form/create";
private static final String POST_FORM = "/config/{channelCode}/create";

@Autowired
SalesService salesService;
    
@Autowired
RuleService ruleService;

@GetMapping(CREATE_FORM)
    public String createForm(@PathVariable String channelCode, @RequestParam(required = false) String error, Authentication authentication, ModelMap model) {       
        UserPrincipal userPrincipal = (UserPrincipal) authentication.getPrincipal();
        SalesDto salesDto = salesService.findByClientIdAndChannelCode(userPrincipal.getUser().getClient().getId(), channelCode);
        List<StoreDto> storeDtos = ruleService.findAllRuleStoreByClientIdAndChannelCode(userPrincipal.getUser().getClient().getId(), channelCode);
        model.addAttribute("channel", salesDto);
        model.addAttribute("stores", storeDtos);
        model.addAttribute("err", error);
        return "configuration/form_create";
    }

@RequestMapping(value=POST_FORM, method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String postForm(
            @ModelAttribute("createForm") StoreDto form, @PathVariable String channelCode, Authentication  authentication, ModelMap model) {

        UserPrincipal userPrincipal = (UserPrincipal) authentication.getPrincipal();
        
        try {
            form.setClientId(userPrincipal.getUser().getClient().getId());
            ruleService.save(form);
        }catch(Exception e) {
            return "redirect:/config/"+form.getChannelCode()+"/form/create?error="+e.getClass().getSimpleName();
        }
        return "redirect:/config/"+form.getChannelCode()+"/list";
    }
```

Comment: Hey, you should pass your model with .addFlashAttribute Here's the example https://stackoverflow.com/a/55945295/12492815

Comment: btw I don't use BindingResult. Is it okay?